# typesafe akka + java fibres

Tags: akka, future, typesafe

Java fibres will help to avoid threads to go into blocking when a blocking code is called.
Will Typesafe Akka get benefitted from this feature, as akka uses Future based approach which results in a lot of context switching.

Answer (score 0):

You might enjoy reading [Will Project Loom obliterate Java Futures?](https://blog.softwaremill.com/will-project-loom-obliterate-java-futures-fb1a28508232) which discusses Loom in the context of Java and Scala Futures.